# How to install and use Tally ERP 9 in Wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I am trying to run Tally ERP 9 (http://www.tallysolutions.com/), post-installation in wine 1.7. I am getting an "out of memory" error, the moment it starts(at the tally splash screen). I then have no option other than to close it.

OS: Xubuntu 12.04.3
Wine:  1.6\1.7.9

How have I installed:

- Inserted the Tally Installation CD, clicked on the tally installer
  executable.
- Installed by following the setup.
- Configured for multi-user, client configuration.
- Server is at a specified LAN address running on Windows.
- Then once installation is done. Clicked on the executable/ran from command line for tally.exe

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now successfully setup Tally ERP 9 on Xubuntu12.04.

Steps to follow:

1. Install wine 1.4(1.5+ or later versions cause Tally ERP 9 to show "out of memory" error)
2. Install Tally ERP 9 using the installer from CD/other media
3. Run Tally ERP 9 from wine menu.
4. To use remote "Data" folder as a client(and Tally Server running on a Windows system), first install samba and cifs-utils. Then type the following command in console:

   `mount.cifs //<your Tally server IP in tally.ini>/<Path to Data folder in tally server> /home/<your username>/.wine/dosdevices/c:/<path to your Data folder in tally.ini> -o uid=<your uid>,gid=<your gid>,rw,nounix,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0666`

   This command should make the Data folder shared in your Tally server to be RW-capable.
5. Use Tally with Wine1.4 as you would on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mount.cifs //<your Tally server IP in tally.ini>/<Path to Data folder in tally server> -o /home/<your username>/.wine/dosdevices/c:/<path to your Data folder in tally.ini>
```

Gives you password and password of shared folder, if any. This worked for me even in wine 1.6. Of course, I had to run tally as super user by going from kdesudo dolphin.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed tally.ERP 9 in ubuntu 12.04 over wine1.7.

First I tried tally in wine version 1.4 and 1.5 over ubuntu version 12.04.Then i understand it require updated wine software.Now I am gonna Explain you,how i installed tally in ubuntu 12.04 over wine 1.7.

Default wine version for ubuntu 12.04 is wine1.4.to get last update add the following repository.

**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa**

and then update it.... using

**sudo apt-get update**

Now,to install wine version 1.7, use

**apt-get install wine1.7**

After complete installation of wine1.7 , right click on .*exe* file and open it by wine loader.

after the complete installation of tally u need to mount the data dir inside the wine application.To do this, use the following command.

**apt-get install cifs-utils**

**mount.cifs     //ServerIPAddre/DataDirPath/      /home/Username/.wine/drive_c/Tally.ERP9/Data/   -o    username=username,password=password,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777**

OR

**echo "//ServerIPAddre/DataDirPath/   /home/Username/.wine/drive_c/Tally.ERP9/Data/    cifs     username=username,password=password,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0" >> /etc/fstab**

Now Open tally application......It will Work................